# Can I use ID in the MappedSuperclass in the Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

There is a problem if I use `$id` in the MappedSuperclass?

I have the following schema, and I need to know if there is some problem use `$id` in the MappedSuperclass.

Thanks.

Example:

```
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
abstract class AbstractBase
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
}
-
/**
* @ORM\MappedSuperclass
*/
abstract class AbstractAddress extends AbstractBase
{

}
-
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="customer_address")
*/
class CustomerAddress extends AbstractAddress
{

}
-
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="order_address")
*/
class OrderAddress extends AbstractAddress
{

}
```